# Does this constitute a magical weapon for the purpose of overcoming resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

I gave my players a halberd which had a magical enchantment that's only purpose was to keep the weapon clean.

Would this be considered magical enough to overcome resistance against non-magical weapons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's entirely up to the DM. Do you consider the home brew weapon as magical for the purpose of bypassing resistance when the effect on it is so minor?

If the DM allows it, then yes, it is magical.

If the DM thinks it's just a flavour thing, then no, it is not magical.

Comment: I thought this effect was in the "create your own magic weapon" table...

Comment: It's under minor properties table on DM pg.143. All of the minor properties are under the special features which is considered flavour or utility use. For example, a sword that is an odd shape could have the "key" property without actually being magical. That's why this table isn't really a "magic weapon" table, but a special feature one.

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing implied by the current rules to suggest that magical weapons do more damage than non magical weapons.  For example, monk attacks eventually count as magical even though that doesn't give them a bonus to damage.

There is also nothing in the DMG that suggests that magical items with flavorful benefits don't count as magical weapons for damage resistance.

Therefore, RAW I would say such a weapon counts.  However if the person who created the magical weapon feels differently, I would cede to their judgement.

Comment: Further backing this answer up, there are many common magic items in *Xanathar's* and other sources that simply provide a minor flavorful benefit; [some of these are weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=9&filter-rarity=1). One example is the *moon-touched sword* from XGtE, and another is the *armblade* from the Eberron books. And, as Crawford has (unofficially) tweeted: ["If a magic item is in the weapon category, it is, indeed, a magic weapon."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/855154905950019584) All that matters here is whether the weapon's a magic item.